# Teams Bot Framework: v3/conversations API return ServiceError

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Trying to send message to user from MS Teams bot app by using https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/<conversation_id>/activities API.

When MS Teams users send messages to my bot app, this is the payload:

```
{
    "text": "Test",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "text/html",
            "content": "<p>Test</p>"
        }
    ],
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2023-02-23T06:04:55.3299493Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2023-02-23T11:34:55.3299493+05:30",
    "id": "16771322XXXXX",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1dg0_w-lYJvMYo-pvGLpU-kQ3SDtAx2JDoj0PTdTbJ4vthgUx_fhckw2y1DUIkAFNRJjmeUNeUJZW0jaR0XXXXX",
        "name": "Maxwell",
        "aadObjectId": "b81d2c1b-2702-4b60-ab63-9c4fefdXXXX"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "conversationType": "personal",
        "tenantId": "a077c4a2-843d-49e8-b5cd-f3b6a77XXXXX",
        "id": "a:1mRkfgE7IToodMtIDgCEjhIvW80fnN3F3NaYPDJykSrQeqpn5tLZSfUP81W-eGdZhQzqpzlBFOvrF2YXzjFmBfknQMyGSRfAppgOxtrwzIsS11hDr1b2OA5tSATfXXXXX"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:4facd6a7-3b3a-4765-83d5-50dc6dbXXXXX",
        "name": "MyBot"
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-GB",
            "country": "GB",
            "platform": "Web",
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ],
    "channelData": {
        "tenant": {
            "id": "a077c4a2-843d-49e8-b5cd-f3b6a77XXXXX"
        }
    },
    "locale": "en-GB",
    "localTimezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
}
```

#### I'm following these STEPs:

1. First creating access_token here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token using my MS Teams Bot Creds.
2. Now sending message to user using access_token from point #1.

This is endpoint: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/a:1mRkfgE7IToodMtIDgCEjhIvW80fnN3F3NaYPDJykSrQeqpn5tLZSfUP81W-eGdZhQzqpzlBFOvrF2YXzjFmBfknQMyGSRfAppgOxtrwzIsS11hDr1b2OA5tSATfXXXXX/activities

Body:

```
{
"type": "message",
"text": "Hello, how are you?",
"from": {
    "id": "28:4facd6a7-3b3a-4765-83d5-50dc6dbXXXXX",
    "name": "MyBot"
},
"serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
"recipient": {
    "id": "29:1dg0_w-lYJvMYo-pvGLpU-kQ3SDtAx2JDoj0PTdTbJ4vthgUx_fhckw2y1DUIkAFNRJjmeUNeUJZW0jaR0XXXXX",
    "name": "Maxwell"
},
"conversation": {
    "id": "a:1mRkfgE7IToodMtIDgCEjhIvW80fnN3F3NaYPDJykSrQeqpn5tLZSfUP81W-eGdZhQzqpzlBFOvrF2YXzjFmBfknQMyGSRfAppgOxtrwzIsS11hDr1b2OA5tSATfXXXXX",
    "tenantId": "a077c4a2-843d-49e8-b5cd-f3b6a77XXXXX"
}
}
```

#### API return this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "message": "Unknown"
    }
}
```

I'm not able to figure out what is the issue.

Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4876

Comment: We tried this at our end and it has worked fine, only difference is our Service URL of bot is 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer'. We will check this internally and get back to you. Similar issue has been reported here at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7613

Comment: The issue is on how bot is constructing the URL when calling Teams service:

The correct way is to use the serviceUrl property from the user message. In the post, it should be https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/. So the endpoint the bot uses to post message to Teams should be:

https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations/a:1mRkfgE7IToodMtIDgCEjhIvW80fnN3F3NaYPDJykSrQeqpn5tLZSfUP81W-eGdZhQzqpzlBFOvrF2YXzjFmBfknQMyGSRfAppgOxtrwzIsS11hDr1b2OA5tSATfXXXXX/activities

In your endpoint it's set to apis instead of in, hence the error. Could you please update the endpoint and try again?